How to increase the size of \bigskip?
I'd like to increase the size of \bigskip. How could I do that?
This is a MWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\bigskip
\lipsum
\end{document}


The size of the vertical offset generated by the instruction \bigskip is governed by  the rubber length -- sorry, some unavoidable TeX jargon here -- parameter \bigskipamount. The LaTeX kernel sets the following default:
\bigskipamount = 12pt plus 4pt minus 4pt

To change it, just issue (say) the following instruction
\bigskipamount = 18pt plus 6pt minus 6pt

Of course, if you want this parameter to be a fixed length rather than a rubber length, you could issue the instruction
\bigskipamount = 18pt

or, equivalently,
\setlength{\bigskipamount}{18pt}

